# Unable to request channel creation using Rest Api

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following Balance-transfer of Hyper-ledger-fabric samples from [Here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer#sample-rest-apis-requests). I have modified it a little. I added 3rd organization. Everything goes fine till I try to create channel using

> curl -s -X POST \
>     http://localhost:4000/channels \
>     -H "authorization: Bearer " \
>     -H "content-type: application/json" \
>     -d '{
>       "channelName":"mychannel",
>       "channelConfigPath":"../artifacts/channel/mychannel.tx"
>   }'

I get below errors:

> error: [Orderer.js]: sendBroadcast - on error: "Error: Connect Failed\n    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:255:19)\n    at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:221:8)\n    at readCallback (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:283:12)"
>   [2018-02-19 15:40:04.991] [ERROR] Create-Channel - Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
>       at ClientDuplexStream. (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Orderer.js:141:21)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:258:12)
>       at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:221:8)
>       at readCallback (/home/atif/Desktop/hyper-ledger/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:283:12)
>   (node:79777) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Failed to initialize the channel: Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
>   (node:79777) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the [ordering service FAQ](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ordering-service-faq.html).  When the ordering service returns an error of:

> SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

this almost always indicates a connection problem between the orderer and Kafka.  This is usually due to one of two reasons:

1. The ordering service has not been given long enough to startup and Kafka is still performing leader election.
2. The Kafka cluster is misconfigured.

I would always encourage users to *first* become familiar with Kafka.  Get the cluster up and running, and send receive messages to/from it, including from other hosts or containers, just like your orderer process will.  Only then should you attempt to deploy Fabric on top of Kafka.  There is a [quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) offered by Kafka which is a good place to start.

Comment: Hey... I face a problem like above question mentioned. I also post my question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994194/hyperledger-explorer-starting-problem-orderer-port-communication-issue .Can you help me on this problem..??