# Hyperledger explorer starting problem- orderer port communication issue

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I just started my hyperledger composer network. Now I need to start hyperledger explorer for this network. I already download the hyperledger explorer github repository using the link https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer. I just try to start the explorer. But get the error in every time that

```
enter Please open web browser to access ：http://localhost:9048/
pid is 31931


[31merror[39m: [Orderer.js]: sendDeliver - rejecting -   status:NOT_FOUND
[31merror[39m: [Orderer.js]: sendDeliver - rejecting - status:NOT_FOUND
[31merror[39m: [Orderer.js]: sendDeliver - rejecting - status:NOT_FOUND
(node:31931) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND
at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/home/myname/Pictures/blockchain-explorer-Production/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Orderer.js:229:22)
at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
at readCallback (/home/myname/Pictures/blockchain-explorer-Production/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:312:14)
(node:31931) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31931) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:31931) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND
at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/home/myname/Pictures/blockchain-explorer-Production/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Orderer.js:229:22)


textProperty config.syncStartDate set to  2018/10/01
```

I think the error is due to orderer service.

I fully checked my orderer port in config.json file of hyperledger explorer.

```
 {
"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "Org1",
        "mspid": "Org1example",
        "peer0": {
            "requests": "grpc://192.168.1.49:7051",
            "events": "grpc://192.168.1.49:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/home/myname/Pictures/Kafka-Fabric-Network-master-3peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
                    "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://192.168.1.49:9051",
            "events": "grpc://192.168.1.49:9053",
            "server-hostname": "peer1.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/home/myname/Pictures/Kafka-Fabric-Network-master-3peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/myname/Pictures/Kafka-Fabric-Network-master-3peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/myname/Pictures/Kafka-Fabric-Network-master-3peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
}

},
"channel": "examplechannel",
"orderers":[
            {
            "mspid": "OrdererOrg",
            "server-hostname":"orderer0.example.com",
            "requests":"grpc://192.168.1.49:7050",
            "tls_cacerts":"/home/myname/Pictures/Kafka-Fabric-Network-master-3peer/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            }
            ],
"keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
"configtxgenToolPath": "/home/myname/Pictures/Kafka-Fabric-Network-master-3peer/bin",
"SYNC_START_DATE_FORMAT":"YYYY/MM/DD",
"syncStartDate":"2018/08/01",
"eventWaitTime": "30000",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"version": "1.1"
}
```

Fabric:1.1.0

Composer:0.19.16

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Explorer: 0.3.4

How it solve. Please give me an idea to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey.. Please give a any help for solve this issue

Comment: My issue is existing. Give any suggestions