# Block chain data will lose in Hyperleger composer network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I Just create a hyper ledger composer network in production level. There are many data(Participant and asset) is existing in my composer blockchain( That is on CouchDB). My main problem is I need to set up a hyper ledger explorer for my existing network. I already use https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer. But the issue is my network orderer port is not synced with explorer( I already post a question regarding this issue [Hyperledger explorer starting problem- orderer port communication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994194/hyperledger-explorer-starting-problem-orderer-port-communication-issue). Unfortunately no replay).

At this moment I decided to stop the running hyper ledger composer network and start again it without any data(participant and asset data) lose. Actually restart the network without data loss is possible...???

Have any other suggestion is available to resolve my issue..???

Any suggestion is much appreciated..

Thank you.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Composer: 0.19.16

Fabric: 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

When you stop your business network using **stopFaric.sh** under **fabric-dev-servers** (or fabric-tools). It will stop fabric Containers and after that run **startFabric.sh** it will recreate new Containers from the Docker Images. Impact of this is that you lose all data(assets, participant, transaction etc) of your business network.

So if you want to **stop** and **start** your **fabric** without loss of existing data. Then follow below **commands** :

Need to change the directory where the docker-compose.yml(`/home/<user>/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer`) file is, and

Run `docker-compose stop` to stop the **Fabric** then

Run `docker-compose start` to restart **Fabric** it will start your network with existing data. Make sure you are in the correct folder.

Hope, it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for responding Isha Padalia. Stoping is possible using the command docker stop $(docker ps -q)  And then start using ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/network-config/docker-compose-kafka.yml up -d. Which is a best practice....???

Comment: Sorry. I got the error that  while try to call composer rest api "message": "Error trying invoke business network with transaction id de88fe44638f57beb2cda9350e140b60386bce0f51d142b7bbeaa41208fc4e7e. Error: Failed to send peer responses for transaction 'de88fe44638f57beb2cda9350e140b60386bce0f51d142b7bbeaa41208fc4e7e' to orderer. Response status 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE'"

Comment: Hey please respond

Comment: I had also successfully restart my business network with the same command. I think your order service was not running perfectly. check your running docker images with `docker ps`.